# Mi programa se salta el IF y me muestra el ELSE

Tags: python-3.x

Código:

```
username = (input ("Ingresa tu usuario "))
password = (input ("Ingresa tu clave "))

if username == "admin" and password == 1234:
    print ("Hola, bienvenido a tu banca online")
else:
    print ("Datos incorrectos, intente de nuevo")
```

Simplemente no muestra el el print del IF, se lo salta y muestra directamente el ELSE, ¿por qué?

Comment: ¿Probaste a poner 
if username == "admin" and password == "1234" a ver si así funciona? Los input reciben strings... Quizás sea por eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema es porque el `input()` devuelve un `string` y en tu `if` tu estas utilizando un entero (int) para evaluar el password

Tienes dos opciones:

### Opción 1

Convierte el input de password a int:

```
username = (input ("Ingresa tu usuario "))
password = int(input ("Ingresa tu clave "))

if username == "admin" and password == 1234:
    print ("Hola, bienvenido a tu banca online")
else:
    print ("Datos incorrectos, intente de nuevo")
```

### Opción 2

Evalúa la contraseña con un string

```
username = (input ("Ingresa tu usuario "))
password = (input ("Ingresa tu clave "))

if username == "admin" and password == '1234':
    print ("Hola, bienvenido a tu banca online")
else:
    print ("Datos incorrectos, intente de nuevo")
```

Comment: Para agregar, es necesario notar que en Python (y probablemente otros lenguajes de programación) 1234 (entero) no es lo mismo que '1234' (cadena).

Comment: Así es, gracias

Comment: Simplemente le he puesto int a la variable password, tenías razón! no todos los héroes usan capa, los míos contestan preguntas en stackoverflow!  A veces me desmotivo, gracias por apoyarme.

Comment: No hay de qué @trying2code, bienvenido a la comunidad. Si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como correcta, de esa forma también ayudamos a otros al no tener preguntas abiertas que ya han recibido una solución

Comment: Con todo gusto, ¿me indicas cómo? nunca había utilizado este foro

Comment: Veo que ya pudiste hacerlo, que tengas buen día